# Why do I get exception for AutoMapper int to int[] array

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using the AutoMapper object mapper, but am getting the exception "Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type."

Basically I have

```
public class Obj1 
{ 
    public int Id {get;set;} 
}
```

and

```
public class Obj2 
{ 
    public int[] Ids { get; set; } 
}
```

Th exception occurs when I try to create the mapping like;

```
Mapper
    .CreateMap<Obj1, Obj2>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Ids[0], o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Id)
);
```

Why is this happening ?  What I'm wanting to achieve is when the objects are mapping that the single int Id in the source is mapped to the first element in the destination int array e.g [0].  The complete exception is

> type="AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException"    message="Custom
>   configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual
>   members on a type."    source="AutoMapper"
>   detail="AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: Custom
>   configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual
>   members on a type.
>    at
>   AutoMapper.Impl.ReflectionHelper.FindProperty(LambdaExpression
>   lambdaExpression)
>    at
>   AutoMapper.MappingExpression`2.ForMember(Expression`1
>   destinationMember, Action`1 memberOptions)
>    at ...

Comment: Can you please add the complete exception (including the stack trace) to your question?

Comment: I've updated my question to include the complete exception.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are close - just need to make the array instead of setting a individual member

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Obj1, Obj2>().ForMember(d => d.Ids, o => o.MapFrom(s => new[]{s.Id}));
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was missing.